# Angular2 Route Changing to the same route if opened in two tabs when the browser tab is idle

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two  Route with only the version change appended to one route. when I open the page in two tabs with version1 in first and version2 in the second tab.
Then I leave  version1 tab ideal for few minutes and work on the version2 tab and then go back to version1 tab the route now changes to version2. this happens vise-versa as well.

```
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: 'Hello',
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
    path: 'Hello',
    component: Route1Component,
    canActivate: [FeaturesGuard],

},
{
    path: 'v2/Hello',
    component: Route2Component,
    canActivate: [FeaturesGuard],

}
```

Comment: That's probably caused by life reload of your development web server express and not related to Angular.

Comment: I think there is some code in your FeaturesGuard, which is handling this redirection. Can you paste the code of this guard.

Comment: there was a problem with my guard implementation which caused the issue.